# In a GWT asynchronous callback, how can I handle the same return types in onSuccess?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

If I have two `boolean`methods in a service, how can I ensure the `onSuccess` method deals with the correct method that is returning a `boolean`?

For example, in the `onSuccess` method I say:

```
if (result instanceof Boolean) {};
```

Is there a way that I can differentiate the service method that is returning the boolean? Otherwise it's impossible to guarantee the right code will execute in my onSuccess method, as if the result is a `boolean` it will execute if either of my two `boolean` service methods are called.

Here's an example of the problem I'm facing:

```
private class DefaultCallback implements AsyncCallback
        {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
            {
            mainGUI.getServerResponseLabel().setStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
            mainGUI.getServerResponseLabel().setHTML("An error occurred while "
                    + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network " + "connection and try again.");
            }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object result)
            {
            if (result instanceof Boolean)
                { 
                //
                I have two methods that return a boolean here, 
                so this block will execute no matter which one is called;
                for one method I want to display a GUI windows saying "Upload complete",          
                and for another, create an excel spreadsheet. But the boolean value of one method won't be relevant to the other
```

Comment: Could you provide and example? What I don't understand is how you can ignore which of the 2 methods you're calling...

Comment: In the AsyncCallBack.onSuccess method, it will call for anytime an Asynchronous callback is successful, with the result - but that result doesn't have any information about what service method has sent it, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: With RPC, you give an asyncCallback parameter to the method, that will be called on success or failure for this specific call. So how could it be wrong?

Comment: OK. Will try and provide an example.

Comment: Example provided, hope I'm actually making sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of grey area, but bear with me:
in     SomethingRPCService.java

```
boolean isA();
boolean isB();
```

in     SomethingRPCServiceAsync.java

```
void isA(AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);
void isB(AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);
```

in your activity

```
somethingService.isA(new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessImpl(final Boolean response) {
            //will be executed on success of THIS call
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
            // not relevant here
        }
});

somethingService.isB(new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessImpl(final Boolean response) {
            //will be executed on success of THIS call
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
            // not relevant here
        }
});
```

You can (have to?) actually type your return

Edit : with your example, I can see a little better; your callback shouldn't be the same, you should override it so the code isn't the same, because it isn't

Comment: Fantastic. I followed a YT tutorial showing a certain way to architect GWT apps, but I never thought of approaching it like this. I would make a custom class that implemetned AsyncCallback and instantiate that class in the parameter of each method, instead of your way. Thanks!!!

Comment: my pleasure ^^. Don't hesitate to define your `onFailure` method in your custom class, so you only have to override the `onSuccess` (if applicable, of course!)

Comment: e.g. this.serviceMethodA.getInputFile(new DefaultCallback());

Comment: In async interface you have `isA` twice. The second should be `isB`. Just a typo, but.... ;)

Comment: +1 now ;) Just as an addition to your answer, it is good to know about `method signature`. @E.Rowlands, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) for example.